# Add row to form which for members?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a signup form which allows the user to add their members. To do this quickly I've created a basic form which has one input, and when the enter key on the keyboard is hit a new row is created.

I've tried the on e key in the input but I can only get this to alert rather than duplicate, here's my form.

```
<form id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <table id="members" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Member Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Member Name" id="member">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>    
        </tr>    
    </table>    
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: write your javscript code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a javascript framework for this. There are several that are capable, but I would recommend Ember.js

Cross-reference this SO question, which is the same question as yours, except in the context of the Embers.js framework:

[Ember: Adding input fields dynamically on click and reading the new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743116/ember-adding-input-fields-dynamically-on-click-and-reading-the-new-data)

It describes clicking a button to reveal a new field, but the same may be done with the filling of a field.

Hoping that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There 's no need for an extra javascript framework. Modern browsers can solve this with HTML5 and native Javascript. Here 's a small example.

```
<template id="my-row">
    <div>
        <label>Member Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Member Name" name="member[]" required>
    </div>
</template>
```

With HTML5 you can use the template tag. It was made for your purpose. The template content does not appear on the screen. It 's just invisible markup. So let 's have a look, what the javascript would look like.

```
<script>
    var template = document.getElementById('my-row');
    var parent = document.querySelector('#members td');
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.key == 'Enter') {
            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            parent.appendChild(clone);
        }    
    });
</script>
```

For example this piece of javascript code does everything what you need. The HTML5 template is inserted as child on pressing the enter key.

The thing you have to deal with: The HTML5 template tag is 'n supported by older browsers. Eventually you have to deal with polymorphs for handling HTML5 template tags in older browsers like the Internet Explorer 11.